# When your controller action respond with json, how to get action_name.js.erb to redirect to another page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, json, controller

My controller action `perform_review` is responding with json. As long as there are an order to fetch, a view partial is re-rendered by `perform_review.js.erb` with the new order, but when we are out of orders to review, `perform_review.js.erb` should redirect to an other page.

The controller looks like this:

```
## orders_controller.rb

class OrdersController < ApplicationController

  def perform_review

    ...

    @order = get_order

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html {
      redirect_to orders_path(current_user)
      }
      format.js {
        if @order == nil
          @redirect_path = orders_path
          return
        end
      }
    end
  end
end
```

And here is the js.erb file:

```
## perform_review.js.erb

if ("<%=@redirect_path %>" != "") {
  location.href = "<%=@redirect_path %>";
}
else
  var order_options_partial = $("#order_options_partial");
  order_options_partial.children().remove();
  order_options_partial.append('<%= j render("order_options") %>');
```

The `else` part works just fine, but the if part does not. The curious thing is that everything is OK in the controller, and `@redirect_path` gets assigned with "/orders". However, it looks like `perform_review.js.erb` does not get triggered after this. To be sure of this I have tried to put in a line that said `console.log("Starting perform_review.js.erb");`, but it does not get called in the browser console...

Comment: ("<%=@redirect_path %>" != "") is return true in this case?
also u don't need to assign @redirecet_path  u could also use in js 
if (<%=@order.blank? %>)
    location.href = orders_path
else
   ---
   ---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in controller as well

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController

  def perform_review

    ...

    @order = get_order

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html {
      redirect_to orders_path(current_user)
      }
      format.js {render :js => "window.location.href = '"+orders_path(current_user)+"'"} if @order.blank?
    end
  end
end
```

In this way you do not need the if else in your `perform_review.js.erb`.
And if you want to do in the view file, then here is the following code.

```
<% if (@order.blank?) %>
  window.location.href = "<%= escape_javascript(@redirect_path) %>";
<% else %>
  // your code
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I can't get it to work though. It looks lige the controller action is now not responding. Are you sure that the string quotations are set right?

Comment: @JohnSmith1976, you are right, some string quotation has been mixed up..it was my mistake. now, I have updated the answer. Can you please check it.

Comment: Arh, so close now. A redirect now happens, but not to the right path: `Started GET "/orders.5219eba783c336c753000d7e" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-09-10 16:33:14 +0200
Processing by OrdersController#index as `

Comment: Ah, I got it to work with this:

`if @order == nil
 format.js {render :js => "window.location.href = '"+orders_path+"'"}
else
 format.js
end`

Without the need for anything in the view file.

Comment: Ummm.. I just missed the current_user to pass in the orders path. I have edited my answer.

Comment: Sorry, shorter version of my previous comment: `format.js {render :js => "window.location.href = '"+orders_path+"'" if @order == nil}`